# Is survival probability the same thing as relative fitness?

Tags: fitness

I created a model where I calculate the survival probabilities from a Mark-recapture design.

I'm wondering if I can call the survival probabilities as "relative fitness".

> Phenotype or genotype: $X$
>   Absolute fitness: $W(X)$
>   Relative fitness: $w(X)=\frac{W(X)}{\bar W}$

Since relative fitness is a ratio, I would have the tendency to say that it's the same thing as survival probability (keeping in mind that survival is only *one* component of fitness, so conceptually not *exactly the same thing*).

If I refer to [this article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2753274/pdf/nihms121275.pdf), since I'm computing survival probabilities per individual, I would just need to call it "individual fitness".

It seems that "relative fitness" is more appropriate with a certain categorical phenotype: the relative fitness of tall vs short plants. If you have a continuous trait, how is the relative fitness interpreted?